# Access File buffer from a Thread Causing AccessViolationException

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio

I have some wav sounds that I want to play from a thread. I load the sounds into memory when the program starts, and I play them using the Windows function PlaySound. This works, but when I try to play the sounds from a thread, I get an AccessViolationException, "Attempted to read or write protected memory".

Is there a way to load a file into a char array, and then read it from a separate thread?

Here is the code I am using to load the sound file and play it.

```html
// Code to load sound from file into char*.
    ifstream ifs(WaveSounds::sounds::StartupMusic, ios::binary | ios::ate);
 // The ios::ate flag sets the filestream
 // to the end position, so it's already
 // ata the end when we call 'tellg()'.
 if (&std::ios::ios_base::good)
 {  
  int length = ifs.tellg();
  ifs.seekg(0, ifs.beg);
  // Load into the Char * , 'n_StartMusic'.
  n_StartMusic = new char[length];
  ifs.read(n_StartMusic, length);
  ifs.close();
 }

// Plays sound from thread, causes AccessViolationException.
static void PlaySoundThread()
{  
 PlaySound((LPWSTR)WaveSounds::n_CurSound, NULL, SND_MEMORY | SND_ASYNC);
}

// Method that sets sound to play and starts thread.
void WaveSounds::Play_Sound(char* sound)
{  
 n_CurSound = sound;
 n_hmod = GetModuleHandle(0);
 Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(PlaySoundThread));
 t->IsBackground = true;
 t->Start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If char* sound is passed into your function on the stack via wave.play_sound(&c); by the time the thread starts c might've been deleted so m_nCurSound is pointing to cleared memory.

To fix this change m_nCurSound=sound to m_nCurSound= new char[255]; strcpy(sound, m_nCurSound);

Comment: Yep, that was it.  The file is loaded in the initializer of the class, but I was testing it by declaring an instance of the class in the same function I called it, so it was loading it into the stack instead of the heap.  When I declared a separate instance of the class and then tried it, it worked fine. Rookie mistake, as I am still new to C++. Thanks!